# Menu from tab bar in storyboarding

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbar

At the moment I have a standard tab bar, when tapped goes to its corresponding viewController. But I want to make a menu pop out from tab bar when more tab is selected, as shown in below image.

[image]

Is any suggestion to implement this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you found the solution for this? I need the same

Comment: It sure as hell looks ugly and is somewhat an anti-pattern. It's _usually_ better to make that fifth tab `push` a newViewController which will then have more options.

Comment: On Tab five, what would be there in background? (the white portion) , would it be the previous selected screen ?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you do so:

First, you should think of all the tab types that could be in tab bar. On your screenshot there are tabs, that present controller, and tab, that presents menu. So we could create enum with all these types:

```
enum TabType {
    case controller
    case menu
}
```

After that you can store array of tab types in order they are shown in tab bar, for your screenshot like so

```
let tabTypes: [TabType] = [.controller, .controller, .controller, .controller, .menu]
```

Then you should implement `UITabBarControllerDelegate`'s `func tabBarController(_:, shouldSelect:) -> Bool` method, which returns `true` if tab bar is allowed to select the passed controller, and `false` otherwise.

If you return `true` than all other work (like presenting view controller and other stuff) tab bar controller will do for you.

In your case you want to execute custom action on tab click, so you should return `false`. Before returning you should present your menu.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if let index = tabBarController.viewControllers?.index(of: viewController),
        index < tabBarTypes.count {
        let type = tabBarTypes[index]
        switch type {
        case .menu:
            // perform your menu presenting here
            return false
        case .controller:
            // do nothing, just return true, tab bar will do all work for you
            return true
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

In this implementation you can easily change tab types order or add some another tab type and handle it appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Its not good UI but although if you want.

First You have to implement delegate method of UITabbarControllerDelegate as below

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect 
 viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if viewController.classForCoder == moreViewController.self
    {   
        let popvc = MoreSubMenuViews(nibName: "MoreSubMenuViews", bundle: Bundle.main)
        self.addChildViewController(popvc)

        let tabbarHeight = tabBar.frame.height
        let estimatedWidth:CGFloat = 200.0
        let estimatedHeight:CGFloat = 300.0
        popvc.view.frame = CGRect(x:self.view.frame.width - estimatedWidth, y: self.view.frame.height - estimatedHeight - tabbarHeight, width: estimatedWidth, height: estimatedHeight)

        self.view.addSubview(popvc.view)

        popvc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        print("sorry stop here")
        return true // if you want not to select return false here

    }else{

        //remove popup logic here if opened
        return true
    }
}
```

Here **moreViewController** is last tab controller & **MoreSubMenuViews** is nib/xib file which contains buttons shown in you image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of showing a menu, you could use a scrollable tabs view for a better UI. If you prefer using a library, [here's](https://github.com/raihan/ZRScrollableTabBar) a simple scrollable tab-bar you could implement.

Comment: post some sample code for author's understanding. If the link is broke, then no one can benefit here

Comment: This answer needs more content

Answer (score 0):

This is an abuse of the UI patterns layout in Apples HIG. Specifically:

> Use a tab bar strictly for navigation. Tab bar buttons should not be used to perform actions. If you need to provide controls that act on elements in the current view, use a toolbar instead.

This control should be used to flatten your app hierarchy. It seems that in this case you are mixing functionality of the button. Sometimes it selects a separate view controller, sometimes it displays a action list. This is a confusing situation for users and should be avoided.

A way you could achieve this and still adhere to HIG is by using navigation or tool bars. Imbed this control in a toolbar button. The most simple case would be to invoke a `UIActionController` with the `.actionSheet` style selected.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you want is that, tab 1 is selected and user goes to tab 5 then background will be tab 1 & vice-versa for tab 2,3 & 4 and there should be pop up like buttons as shown in your image. please correct me if I'm wrong.

For this you have to capture the image while user navigate through tabs.

Please find below code in **AppDelegate**,

`var currentImage: UIImage! //It will be public variable`

Tabbar delegate methods,

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 4 {
        let moreVC = tabBarController.selectedViewController as! MoreVC
        moreVC.currentImage = currentImage
    }
}

func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    if tabBarController.selectedIndex != 4 {
        let navController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as! UINavigationController
        let viewController = navController.viewControllers.last
        currentImage = Common.imageWithView(inView: (viewController?.navigationController?.view)!) //UIImage(view: (viewController?.navigationController?.view)!)
    }

    return true
}
```

Here I've taken static 4 as last tab index & MoreVC will be the associated ViewController of tab index 4.

Common class to get image from view,

```
class Common {
    static func imageWithView(inView: UIView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inView.bounds.size, inView.isOpaque, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            inView.layer.render(in: context)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Please find MoreVC,

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var currentImage: UIImage! {
    didSet {
        imageView.image = currentImage
    }
}
```

Please find below image for MoreVC Storyboard. Look it does not contain NavigationController like all other ViewControllers.

[image]

Let me know in case of any queries.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
Create a "Tab5ViewController" and use this:

```
static func takeScreenshot(bottomPadding padding: CGFloat = 0) -> UIImage? {
        let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: layer.frame.size.width, height: layer.frame.size.height - padding), false, scale)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        layer.render(in: context)
        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshot
    }
```

Use the screenshot as a background image for your "Tab5ViewController"

**2)** In your "Tab5ViewController" you can have the stack component (the additional tabs) and then just add/remove child view controllers based on the selection

**3)** 
fix edge cases (like tab selection highlight and so on...)